# Who are the Mansons?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural season 12, the Winchesters' mother says she needed time-off. Finally (in another episode), Dean is not all that okay with this fact. Sam tries to convince Dean by saying families do better if they do some time apart. To which Dean sarcastically asks - "yeah like who...the Mansons?"

So what's the story behind the Mansons?

Comment: It should be noted that "the Manson Family" isn't actually a family in the traditional sense. It was a cult following a man who was able to brainwash or manipulate a group of people to commit probably the first US home invasions, targeting (and killing) celebrities and ransacking their homes, during the 1960s.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking "Who are the Mansons?":

I have never seen the show but they are probably referring to the [Manson Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manson_Family), a community lead by the murderer [Charles Manson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Manson) who were thought to be crazy due to the fact that they believed in what Manson told them.

If you are asking "Why do the Mansons need some time apart?":

To quote the Wikipedia article linked above,

> They [the Family] roamed as far north as Washington state, then southward through Los Angeles, Mexico, and the southwest. Returning to the Los Angeles area, they lived in Topanga Canyon, Malibu, and Venice—western parts of the city and county.

implying that they were very close, having lived in a van together for months.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Beat me to the punch by about ten seconds. =)

Comment: @Steve-O Only because I was reading about Charles Manson right now. (Don't ask) So I had the wiki page open when I saw the question :)

Comment: *"...families do better if they **do some time apart.**"* Assuming this is a direct quote, note that "do some time" is slang for being sent to prison... which is where Manson and his surviving followers likely are right now, and they've surely been separated from one another. ;)

Comment: @Steve-O well 3 of them have died and Manson almost died on New Years from "gastrointestinal bleeding".